# SQL Server Optional Parameter Date from to

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure and I want to search between the from and to date, but:

```
if @FromDate is not null and @ToDate is not null then 
vSaleDetail.date  between @FromDate and @ToDate 

if @FromDate is not null and @ToDate is null then
vSaleDetail.date = @FromDate

if @FromDate is null and @ToDate is then
Return All
```

This is what I have but it is not working

```
where
(((@FromDate is null and @ToDate is null) OR  (vSaleDetail.date  between @FromDate and @ToDate ))
AND ((@FromDate is null) OR  (vSaleDetail.date = @FromDate)))
```

Please help — what do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I would poulate the null parameters with dates way outside the range you need. So If form date is null, I would populate with the earlies t accepatable date in your database's datetime data type. The To date would be poulated with the latest possible date. Then you don't need to use all that complex logic which slows things down.

```
IF @FromDate is null
Begin 
Set @Fromdate = '17530101'
END

IF @ToDATE is null
BEGIN 
SET @Todate = '99991231'
END

select ...
WHERE  vSaleDetail.date  >=@FromDate and <= @ToDate
```

Comment: This doesn't completely match the logic as laid out by the OP. If `@FromDate` is not null and `@ToDate` is null, they seem to want the date column to match the `@FromDate` only.

Comment: It will cover that case because the to date is so far out it encompasses all their records.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. When `@FromDate` is not null and `@ToDate` is null, the end result with your query would be the rows matching the *range* starting from the `@FromDate` and up. However, the OP's requirement for this case appears to be that `vSaleDetail.date = @FromDate` *only*.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
WHERE (vSaleDetail.date BETWEEN @FromDate AND ISNULL(@ToDate,@FromDate)
    OR COALESCE(@FromDate, @ToDate) IS NULL)
```

`ISNULL(p1, p2)`:

if p1 `IS NULL` then p2 is returned, otherwise p1 is returned

`COALESCE(p1, p2, ...)`:

Like `ISNULL()`.  returns p1 unless it is `NULL`, in which case, p2 is returned unless it is `NULL`, in which case p3....  if all parameters in `COALESCE()` are null, `NULL` is returned.

Comment: the purpose of the `COALESCE()` portion is to test for both parameters being NULL in which case, there is effectively no filter and all values are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    WHERE
    ( 
        ( @FromDate IS NULL AND @ToDate IS NULL)
        OR 
        ( vSaleDetail.date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate )
    )
    OR <-- @FromDate IS NULL AND @FromDate IS NULL
( @FromDate IS NULL OR vSaleDetail.date = @FromDate )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @default_min_date datetime;
declare @default_max_date datetime;

SET @default_min_date = 0
SET @default_max_date = 2958463;

SELECT  *
FROM    MyTable
WHERE
        myDateColumn >= Isnull(@DateFrom, @default_min_date) AND myDateColumn <= Isnull(@DateTo, @default_max_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

AND (@DateFrom IS NULL OR CONVERT(DATETIME, [CreationDate], 103) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @DateFrom, 103) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, ISNULL(@DateTo, @DateFrom), 103)))